# Mysqli update data if data exactly match with database

Tags: php, mysql

Already i successful to Insert data from sms and my sms content[$text_utf8] inserted by two columns[$p_n and $msg]. Now my question is

When the customer send a sms with a code[$p_n] [which was i provided]. The sms script find out the code[$p_n] from database if code[$p_n] exactly match with customer sms pin [$text_utf8, $p_n]. then update some columns like $msg and $phone.

```
 $phone = $_GET["phone"];

      $ix=strpos($text_utf8,' ');
      if($ix!==false) {
        $p_n=trim(substr($text_utf8, 0, $ix));
        $msg=trim(substr($text_utf8, $ix+1));

        if(strlen($p_n)!=0 && strlen($msg)!=0) {
          $wrong_format=FALSE;

          $p_n = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $p_n);
          $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $msg);


          // creating an sql statement to insert the message into the pin_man table
          $sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg' AND phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n'";
          // executing the sql statement
          mysqli_query($con,$sql);      
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query should be like this use , insted of and

```
$sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg', phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n'";
```

Comment: now one more thing . if the $msg and $phone data already exist then it will  not update, how can i do it.

Comment: tell me @Md.muzahidulislamtanveer

Comment: that means i want to update only when the pin code match and the $msg and $phone data null. if $msg and $phone data exist then it will not update

Comment: you want update only when $msg and $phone is null is it ? you just add $sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg', phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n' and (message_column_name=null or message_column_name='') and (phone_column_name=null or phone_column_name='')";

Comment: i used this code not working     $sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg', phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n' and (p_n=null or p_n='') and (phone=null or phone='')";

Comment: what you want do exactly ?

Comment: i want to update data if $msg and $phone null , i used your code it's not working

Comment: above code give you solution for what you expected @Md.muzahidulislamtanveer

Comment: your passing p_n is in where condition WHERE p_n='$p_n'    then why how you get p_n=null  think logically

Comment: and (p_n=null or p_n='') remove this condition  .it will work @Md.muzahidulislamtanveer

Comment: $sql="UPDATE smss SET msg='$msg', r_date=CURDATE(), r_time=CURTIME(), phone='$phone' WHERE p_n='$p_n' and (p_n=null or p_n='') and (phone=null or phone='')"   THAT'S also work but when i use CURDATE() and CURTIME() it's update wrong date maybe that was not my area timezone. so how can i change my timezone while update CURDATE() AND CURTIME() into Malaysia/Kuala Lumpur timezone, can u help me please?

Comment: if you want change the php time zone follow this one date_default_timezone_set('Malaysia/Kuala');  if you want in mysql means you have change it in your server because mysql taking server time @Md.muzahidulislamtanveer

Comment: you also find the the timezone setup in php.ini file replace your wish timezone

Comment: where i put this line date_default_timezone_set('Malaysia/Kuala Lumpur'); and my hosting is godaddy already i put this script to php.ini file but it's not work....

Comment: find the [Date] in your php.ini file there to place the below line

date.timezone ="Malaysia/Kuala Lumpur"

Comment: ALREADY i put this script date.timezone ="Malaysia/Kuala Lumpur" at php.ini file but no change